# ASP.NET Core BundleMinifier removes async modifier after minification

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, bundle, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-core-3.1

I added [`bundleconfig.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification) to ASP.NET Core application. It has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/main.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/scripts/first.js",
      "wwwroot/js/scripts/second.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Both scripts has been minified and merged into `main.min.js`. But after minification all `async` modifiers has been removed from result script.

Function such as

```
async function foo() {
  await /* some promise */;
}
```

have been turned into:

```
function foo() {await /*some promise*/;}
```

How do I avoid removing `async` modifier?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core?

Comment: My guess would be that you are running into [this issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/311). Are you using the "Bundler & Minifier" VS extension, or the `BundlerMinifier.Core` NuGet package?

Comment: seems to be an ongoing issue since 2017... Maybe change bundler?

Comment: Sorry, dear bro, which tool bundle and minified your JavaScript codes?

Comment: function foo() {await /*some promise*/;} how does it possible ? using await in non-async method .do you encounter error when using BundleMinifier?

Comment: @IanKemp ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: @Mr.AF Function `foo` before minification has `async` modifier. But after minification `async` has been removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'v reproduced the issue and tried to minify a simple js file that using `ES6 specifications` and later.

Test.js

```
async function foo() {
    await bar();
}
async function bar() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // do some work
    }
}
```

Then i tried to minify the file with [Bundler and Minifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) tool then this error thrown:

[image]

This means **Bundler and Minifier doesn't support ES6 specifications and later.**

For confirmation i started searching about this issue in the [Github](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) and i found these same behaviors

- [Crash on ES6 arrow functions in source files](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/277)
- [minify es6 js file without turning them to es5](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/347)
- [Where BundleMinifier currently is usefull (and where not)](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/339)

I can surely claim that this is The [Transpilers](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) Issue

> Transpilers, or source-to-source compilers, are tools that read source
>   code written in one programming language, and produce the equivalent
>   code in another language.

The most common and widely use one is [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

`TypeScript` in some cases Transpiles `ES6` and later to `ES5`

**For example:** if you set Target to `ES6` and `ES2015` it Transpiles to `ES5`. However, if You Target to `ES2020` does NOT Transpile your code.

### At The End

- BundlerMinifier uses NUglify that perform javascript code
  minification So There is NO way minifying ES6 and later codes by
  using Bundler and Minifier. Unless, The Author decides to support it.
- You are encountering The Transpile Issue (ex:ES6 to ES5).
- **Bundler & Minifier** doesn't remove unknown keywords like `async` but thrown error